# Decide p, q values based on acf and pacf

Tags: python, arima

I need to know the way how to calculate/decide the p and q value for ARIMA model based on the acf and the pacf graph. Kindly help.

In the description, I have posted part of my Data, so anyone can try this out to give an explanation regarding the posted data set. 
What I'm looking forward is instructions to analyze such a dataset, so I can predict future values correctly. I'm looking forward to use models such as Arima, SARIMA etc. My main need is to find the parameters for ARIMA and SARIMA

[image]

```
Date    Gross_Premium
1/15/2012   0
2/15/2012   0
3/15/2012   0
4/15/2012   51579.01
5/15/2012   0
6/15/2012   50113.93681
7/15/2012   16854.74714
8/15/2012   61246.11
9/15/2012   0
10/15/2012  3497.14
11/15/2012  0
12/15/2012  0
1/15/2013   0
2/15/2013   0
3/15/2013   0
4/15/2013   111803.15
5/15/2013   10800
6/15/2013   11852.22681
7/15/2013   22619.05368
8/15/2013   70548.52
9/15/2013   5752.72
10/15/2013  6994.28
11/15/2013  0
12/15/2013  0
1/15/2014   0
2/15/2014   0
3/15/2014   0
4/15/2014   94724.14
5/15/2014   10800
6/15/2014   38261.71
7/15/2014   15800.22125
8/15/2014   39388.17
9/15/2014   32569.36
10/15/2014  0
11/15/2014  0
12/15/2014  0
1/15/2015   0
2/15/2015   0
3/15/2015   0
4/15/2015   110144.68
5/15/2015   0
6/15/2015   47835.92
7/15/2015   27637.08915
8/15/2015   72842.2
9/15/2015   5838.51
10/15/2015  3497.14
11/15/2015  0
12/15/2015  0
1/15/2016   0
2/15/2016   0
3/15/2016   0
4/15/2016   167626.54
5/15/2016   21600
6/15/2016   30988.9368
7/15/2016   19109.44915
8/15/2016   98501.16
9/15/2016   20892.34
10/15/2016  6994.28
11/15/2016  0
12/15/2016  0
1/15/2017   0
2/15/2017   0
3/15/2017   0
4/15/2017   96382.61
5/15/2017   10800
6/15/2017   30988.9368
7/15/2017   20246.65096
8/15/2017   61423.9
9/15/2017   16284.68
10/15/2017  3497.14
11/15/2017  0
12/15/2017  0
```

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: I think it is a statistics/modelling question rather than a programming problem. I would suggest you to to ask it in [https://stats.stackexchange.com/](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took one of your problems sets (ALPHBET)   [image]and analyzed it as follows. Although you have observations for 12 months of the year ....there are 5 months that have no sales for every year thus falsely suggesting strong autoregressive structure .

I have previously run into this when predicting beer sales for products that are only sold for some months of the year ...think Octoberfest Beers. The answer to this is to simply redefine your "year" to have 7 working months ( less months 11,12,1,2,3 ).

Following is a graph of the data with 7 observations/periods per year .  [image]

The good news is that there is strong DETERMINISTIC seasonality i.e. certain months of the 7 have systematic predictable sales. This requires the use of five seasonal dummies rather than memory (SARIMA) . Following is a useful equation augmented with 6 pulses. [image]

The Actual,Fit and Forecast graph is here [image] and forecasts here   [image]for the next 7 periods covering  the next 3 years with confidence limits explicitely allowing for unusual values.

The Actual & Cleansed graph is here [image] illuminating the unusual values. Finally the residual plot suggests randomness [image] supported by the ACF of the residuals [image]

Your question is answered : There is no useful SARIMA MODELfor your data as it is driven by deterministic effects AND not memory.

In closing, perhaps some helpful reader of SE might actually explain how one attaches a csv file containing the data rather than one actually having to list it as you courtesly did.